# Outputting the desired value on a drop down menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a site where there is this drop down menu when in mobile screen. It offers the user to chose different categories of a service. When you chose a category, the site sends you to the right page.

The problem is, the drop down menu goes back to it's original value (All). I would like it to display the page it is on. Meaning if the user chose commercial the menu will display commercial, not go back to All.

this is the code for the drop down menu:

```
<select class="news-filters-select" name="news-filters-select" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="http://example.com/fr/service/renovation/">All</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/fr/service/renovation/categorie/commercial">Commercial</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/fr/service/renovation/categorie/multilogements">Multilogements</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/fr/service/renovation/categorie/residentiel">Residentiel</option>
</select>
```

I tried different things with jquery but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    // After loading of select element, select option which has value as current web page's URL
    $('select.news-filters-select').val($('select.news-filters-select option[value="'+location+'"]').val());            
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure, what do you mean by +location+?

Comment: Javascript's Window location object is representing current web page's URL, which is the same as you used in onchange event handler. You can use it to either get current web page's URL or redirect browser to other URL. '+' is used to concatenate strings.

Comment: Are you adding this script to all the pages in the options? Like webpage for commercial, residentiel etc.?

Comment: No I thought I had to make a function in a separated js file. You mean I should add this directly in the html mark-up?

Comment: This script should run in every html page. You can have one seperate file (for example, script.js) for this script and include that file in all HTML pages mentioned above (commercial, residentiel etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85469/discussion-between-cpshah-and-christian-pineault).